# Linking two classes

Tags: java, oop

sorry to be annoying, I am new to programming and am a bit confused.

How do I link variables of two classes? ie get a variable of one class into another? I'm trying to make an OOP scenario for a game platform where a player can join a game(max of 2 players per game, and pay an associated fee. I;'m trying to get a method which totals these in the Game class but I'm unsure how to add up all the players "amountOwed" into this. I also have to make sure both players are not the same player? any advice GREATLY appreciated! here is what i have so far

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Period;
import java.util.Date;

public class Player {
    private static int instanceCounter = 0;
    private int playerId;
    private String playerName;
    public int birthDay;
    public int birthMonth;
    public int birthYear;
    public int playerAge;
    public double amountOwed;

    public Player(int playerId, String playerName, int birthDay, int birthMonth, int birthYear, double amountOwed) {
        this.playerId = playerId;
        this.playerName = playerName;
        this.birthDay = birthDay;
        this.birthMonth = birthMonth;
        this.birthYear = birthYear;
        this.amountOwed = amountOwed;
        instanceCounter++;
    }

    public double getAmountOwed() {
        return (amountOwed);
    }

    public int calculateAge() {
        LocalDate birthDate = LocalDate.of(birthYear, birthMonth, birthDay);
        LocalDate currentDate = LocalDate.now();
        return playerAge = Period.between(birthDate, currentDate).getYears();
    }

    public String printDetails() {
        return (playerName + ", with ID " + playerId + ", is " + playerAge + " and owes the game platform£" + amountOwed);

    }

    public String payFees() {
        amountOwed = 0;
        return ("Thank you" + playerName + ",you have paid for your game, your balance now stands at £0.00");
    }

    public String joinGameChess() {
        if (instanceCounter < 3) {
            return (playerName + " has joined the game.");
        } else {
            return ("Sorry, maximum of 2 players per game");
        }
    }

    public String leaveGame() {
        return (playerName + "has left the game.");
    }
}

public class Game {
    private String gameName;
    private int gameId;
    private int minAge;
    private double fee;
    public double amountOwed;
    public double totalFeesOwed;

    public Game(String gameName, int gameId, int minAge, double fee) {
        this.gameId = gameId;
        this.gameName = gameName;
        this.minAge = minAge;
        this.fee = fee;

    }

    public String printGameDetails() {
        return (gameName + "of ID " + gameId + "has a minimum age of " + minAge + " and costs " + fee + " to play");
    }
}

public class W07Practical {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Player marina = new Player(123, "Marina", 15, 4, 1999, 0);
        marina.calculateAge();
        System.out.println(marina.printDetails());

        Game chess = new Game("chess", 1234, 19, 2);

        marina.getAmountOwed();
        System.out.println(marina.joinGameChess());

        Player elise = new Player(153, "elise", 16, 3, 2000, 0);
        System.out.println(elise.joinGameChess());

        Player john = new Player(322, "john", 23, 5, 2002, 0);

        System.out.println(john.joinGameChess());

        System.out.println(john.printDetails());
        System.out.println(elise.printDetails());
    }
}
```

Comment: If you just want to add a fee if the user is playing with another player you could have a `boolean isTwoPlayer;` and in your `getAmount` return the according amount according to `isTwoPlayer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Total amount owed:

```
amountOwed = player1.getAmountOwed() + player2.getAmountOwed();
```

You can check both players are not same by their name or to be more precise by comparing their birthdays. For further precision compare both

Comment: would I do this in the main method? how do I get the amount Owed to be stored in the game class if it involves players? are player1 and player2 just example names?

Comment: Yes use this in the main method after creating two players. Yes they are dummy names replace them with whatever name you want

Comment: to allow 2 players only run a loop exactly 2 times to create player object

Comment: You will get the player information input at run time right? or are you going to use haradcoded values

Comment: Arahasya- What would that code for the loop look like?